# Add sorting to this select

Tags: postgresql

**PostgreSQL 15.2**

```
select
       current.id as currentId,
       current.date as currentDate,
       current.position as currentPosition,
       current.relevant_url as currentRelevantUrl,
       current.restrictions_probability as currentRestrictionsProbability,
       current.url_changed as currentUrlChanged,
       current.identifier_id as currentIdentifierId,
       current.phrase_id as phraseId,
       previous.id as previousId,
       previous.date as previousDate,
       previous.position as previousPosition,
       previous.relevant_url as previousRelevantUrl,
       previous.restrictions_probability as previousRestrictionsProbability,
       previous.url_changed as previousUrlChanged,
       previous.identifier_id as previousIdentifierId,
       semantics_clusters.id as clusterId,
       semantics_clusters.name as clusterName,
       site_pages.id as pageId,
       site_pages.url as pageUrl,
       site_pages.site_id as siteId,
       site_sites.url as siteUrl,
       semantics_core_phrases.frequency as frequency
from (
select
       id,
       date,
       position,
       relevant_url,
       restrictions_probability,
       url_changed,
       identifier_id,
       phrase_id
from overoptimisation
where identifier_id = 1) current

left join (
select
       id,
       date,
       position,
       relevant_url,
       restrictions_probability,
       url_changed,
       identifier_id,
       phrase_id
from overoptimisation
where identifier_id = 1) previous

on current.phrase_id = previous.phrase_id
inner join semantics_core_phrases on current.phrase_id = semantics_core_phrases.id
inner join semantics_clusters on semantics_core_phrases.cluster_id = semantics_clusters.id
inner join site_pages on semantics_clusters.page_id = site_pages.id
inner join site_sites on site_pages.site_id = site_sites.id
```

This select works. But I have failed to add sorting.

How can I add order by for these fields?

1. siteId
2. pageId
3. clusterId
4. frequency

Comment: Why is this difficult?  Surely you just add an `ORDER BY` to your query as described by any SQL tutorial

Comment: Syntax errors appear if I insert "order by" anywhere.

Comment: Please post the query that gives you the error and the full complete error message. Post as text - **no images**.

Comment: Since there is no full problem statement here, the question is off-topic, and must be closed. Please always respond to requests to improve questions, even if an acceptable answer has been supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem to add `order by` clause.

Basically your SQL is valid, you can check it, for example, [here](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/)

If you add `order by` clause in the end, then it is valid too:

```
select
  current.id as currentId,
  current.date as currentDate,
  current.position as currentPosition,
  current.relevant_url as currentRelevantUrl,
  current.restrictions_probability as currentRestrictionsProbability,
  current.url_changed as currentUrlChanged,
  current.identifier_id as currentIdentifierId,
  current.phrase_id as phraseId,
  previous.id as previousId,
  previous.date as previousDate,
  previous.position as previousPosition,
  previous.relevant_url as previousRelevantUrl,
  previous.restrictions_probability as previousRestrictionsProbability,
  previous.url_changed as previousUrlChanged,
  previous.identifier_id as previousIdentifierId,
  semantics_clusters.id as clusterId,
  semantics_clusters.name as clusterName,
  site_pages.id as pageId,
  site_pages.url as pageUrl,
  site_pages.site_id as siteId,
  site_sites.url as siteUrl,
  semantics_core_phrases.frequency as frequency
from
  (
    select
      id,
      date,
      position,
      relevant_url,
      restrictions_probability,
      url_changed,
      identifier_id,
      phrase_id
    from
      overoptimisation
    where
      identifier_id = 1
  ) current
  left join (
    select
      id,
      date,
      position,
      relevant_url,
      restrictions_probability,
      url_changed,
      identifier_id,
      phrase_id
    from
      overoptimisation
    where
      identifier_id = 1
  ) previous on current.phrase_id = previous.phrase_id
  inner join semantics_core_phrases on current.phrase_id = semantics_core_phrases.id
  inner join semantics_clusters on semantics_core_phrases.cluster_id = semantics_clusters.id
  inner join site_pages on semantics_clusters.page_id = site_pages.id
  inner join site_sites on site_pages.site_id = site_sites.id
order by
  siteId
```

The same way you can order by pageId, clusterId, frequency